# How can i RE-execute a particular function,after getting the response of that function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, delay, nodemailer

okay so this is what I wanna do,
I want to hold the iteration of my for loop until I get a response back from a function call.

I used the setTimeout() function but it just doesn't work.

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    sendMail(); <<--- Hold the iteration until this function completes and returns a value

    //Some other code which should be executed after sendMail() has returned a value
}
```

Comment: I imagine `sendMail` is asynchronous...? Make sure your `sendMail` is returning a promise. Then change it to `await sendMail();`. The code you've shown us will need to be wrapped in an `async` function instead of a normal `function`. For more information: [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_awai).

Comment: You would either have to `await sendMail` or push the function call to an array and after the for loop call `Promise.all(arr)`

Answer (score 0):

Wait until the Promise resolves, if so do whatever you need. Make sure to also handle errors:

```
sendMail() {
  fetch('/backend-endpoint-url`).then(response => response.json());
    .then(response => {
      // do whatever you need when the endpoint resolves
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // error handling here
    });
}
```